# Adiabatic approximation and time-dependent problems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, approximations, adiabatic

I am an undergraduate physics student. I have a question in approximation methods for time-dependent problems in quantum mechanics. I read the proof of the [adiabatic theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) but I didn't understand it. This theorem states:

> *If the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ changes very slowly with time, a system which is initially in a discrete non-degenerate state $u(0)$ with energy $E(0)$ is very likely to go over to the corresponding state $u(t)$ with energy $E(t)$ at time $t$, without making any transition.*

Could you present a comprehensive and simple proof for it?